# Stack Overflow Error Implementing Quicksort (with duplicates) in C#

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, quicksort

I am working on a project and I have to implement Quicksort. I am having a stack overflow issue when I run Quicksort on an array of random integers (of size 100,000). I believe that I am running into an error that involves duplicate values. I attempted to research this problem and someone mentioned to consider when `data[left] == pivot == data[right]` but I don't know what to do with that in my case.

This is for my class so I am required to use this partitioning method, and I created the Quicksort method based off of instructions. Any help will be greatly appreciated. I'd like to figure out what I am doing wrong.

```
public static int Partition(int[] a, int left, int right, int pivotIndex) {
   int temp;
   int pivotValue = a[pivotIndex];
   a[pivotIndex] = a[right];
   a[right] = pivotValue;

   int store = left;
   for (int i = left; i < right; i++) {
      if (a[i] < pivotValue) {
         temp = a[store];
         a[store] = a[i];
         a[i] = temp;
         store++;
      }
   }
   temp = a[right];
   a[right] = a[store];
   a[store] = temp;

   return store;
}

public static void Quicksort(int[] a, int left, int right) {
   if ((right - left) <= 5)
      InsertionSort(a);
   else if (left < right) {
      int mid = ((right - left) / 2) + left;
      int pivot = Math.Max(Math.Min(a[left], a[right]), Math.Min(Math.Max(a[left], a[right]), a[mid]));
      int pivotIndex = Array.IndexOf(a, pivot);

      Partition(a, left, right, pivotIndex);
      Quicksort(a, left, (pivotIndex - 1));
      Quicksort(a, (pivotIndex + 1), right);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is in the way you choose the pivot index.

Although you are correctly choosing the median of three value, you are not finding the index of that median correctly.

Firstly, this is incorrect:

```
int pivotIndex = Array.IndexOf(a, pivot);
```

That will find the index of the first occurrence of the median value in the entire `a[]` array.

At the very least it should be like this:

```
int pivotIndex = Array.IndexOf(a, pivot, left, right-left+1);
```

However that still has several problems:

1. You will be doing a linear search for the pivot value over the entire partition. This is very inefficient.
2. It will find the first occurrence of the median value, regardless of what the actual index is.
3. If the left, right or mid values are the same, it should choose the mid index, but the linear search will choose the left index.

The solution is to change the way you compute the median of three so that you calculate the actual index rather just the value. This is rather more fiddly!

Comment: Thank you for your response. I thought I calculated the median of the three in the above line `int pivot = Math.Max(Math.Min(a[left], a[right]), Math.Min(Math.Max(a[left], a[right]), a[mid]));` Oh I see now. I previously had code that found out which exact choice from `a[left] a[right] a[mid]` using if statements, but I figured using `Array.IndexOf()` would be simpler. I get now that I could have gotten any index with the similar value. I'll edit it and hope that it works. Thank you!

Comment: I just finished the edits and it worked! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

First I would recommend you to shuffle array before sorting, or at least check median value (or ninther) and use it during partitioning, it will probabilistically guarantee O(NLogN).

Also if you have duplicates it is a good idea to use [3 way partitioning](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/3-way-quicksort/). Below is an implementation of quick sort with three way partitioning and shuffling.

```
public static void Quicksort(int[] a) {
    if (a == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Array is null");
    Shuffle(a);
    Quicksort(a, 0, a.Length - 1);
}

private static void Quicksort(int[] a, int left, int right) {
    if ((right - left) <= 5)
        InsertionSort(a);
    else if (left <= right) {
        int lt = left, gt = right;
        int v = a[left];
        int i = left;
        while (i <= gt) {
            if      (a[i] < v) Swap(a, lt++, i++);
            else if (a[i] > v) Swap(a, i, gt--);
            else              i++;
        }

        // a[lo..lt-1] < v = a[lt..gt] < a[gt+1..hi]. 
        Quicksort(a, left, lt - 1);
        Quicksort(a, gt + 1, right);
    }
}

public static void Shuffle(int[] a) {
    if (a == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("Array is null");
    int n = a.Length;
    var theRandom = new Random();
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int r = i + theRandom.Next(n-i);     // between i and n-1
        int temp = a[i];
        a[i] = a[r];
        a[r] = temp;
    }
}

private  static void InsertionSort<T>(T[] array) where T:IComparable<T>
{
    for (var i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
    {
        var value = array[i];
        var j = i - 1;
        while ((j >= 0) && (array[j].CompareTo(value) > 0))
        {
            array[j + 1] = array[j--];
        }
        array[j + 1] = value;
    }
}

private static void Swap(int[] a, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = a[i];
    a[i] = a[j];
    a[j] = tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class QuickSortExample
{
    static int Partition(int[] arr, int left, int right)
    {
        int pivot = arr[left + ((right - left) / 2)]; // use a midpoint pivot to prevent worst case O(n log n), although pivot = arr[left] is fine

        while (left < right)
        {
            while (arr[left] < pivot)
                left++;
            while (arr[right] > pivot)
                right--;

            // handle duplicate entries
            if (arr[right] == pivot && arr[left] == pivot)
                left++;

            if (left < right)
            {
                int tmp = arr[right];
                arr[right] = arr[left];
                arr[left] = tmp;
            }
        }
        return right;
    }

    static void QuickSort(int[] arr, int left, int right)
    {
        if(left < right)
        {
            int pivot = Partition(arr, left, right);

            if (pivot > 1)
                QuickSort(arr, left, pivot - 1);

            if(pivot + 1 < right)
                QuickSort(arr, pivot + 1, right);
        }
    }

    static void TestQuickSort(int[] arr)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Initial array[" + arr.Length + "] = { " + string.Join<int>(", ", arr) + " }");

        QuickSort(arr, 0, arr.Length - 1);

        Console.WriteLine("Sorted  array[" + arr.Length + "] = { " + string.Join<int>(", ", arr) + " }\n");
    }

    static void QuicksortTestRandom(int maxSize)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        int[] randomValues = new int[r.Next(maxSize)];
        for (int i = 0; i < randomValues.Length; i++)
        {
            randomValues[i] = r.Next(-999, 999);
        }
        TestQuickSort(randomValues);
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("QuickSort (Recursive), complexity = O(n log n)\n");

        int[][] TestArrays = new int[][] {
            new int[] { 6, 2, 5, 8, 1, 10, 0, 3, 7, 9, 4 },
            new int[] { 3, 5, 4, 2, 5, 3, 5, 2, 4, 3, 5, 5, 4, 1, 4 },
            new int[] { 67, 12, 95, 56, 1, 85, 85, 1, 100, 23, 60, 9, 0, 85, 0, 85, 85, 90, 85, 85 },
            new int[] { 1 },
            new int[] { 0, 0 },
            new int[] { 1, 0 },
            new int[] { 0, 1 },
            new int[] { 1, 0, 2 },
            new int[] { 1, 0, 1, 0 },
            new int[]  {2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1 },
            new int[] { 1, 0, -1 },
            new int[] { },
            new int[] { 1, 3, 6, 2, 7, 5, -1, 4, 8, 9, 0 },
        };

        foreach(int[] arr in TestArrays)
        {
            TestQuickSort(arr);
        }

        QuicksortTestRandom(16);

        Console.WriteLine("done... press enter to end.\n");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a block of code is not very helpful: What code did you change? How did you change it? You added the bottom 3 methods, maybe you can put those in a separate code block with a brief introduction 'And you can test it using these methods'.